# LinkedList class implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, unit-testing, linked-list

I was solving this problem for implementing `LinkedList` and `ListNode` classes, and `Insert` and `Remove` methods for `LinkedList`. I was wondering if I can get any code review and feedback.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this node"""
        return 'Node({})'.format(repr(self.value))

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """Initialize this linked list and append the given items, if any"""
        """Best case Omega(1)"""
        """Worst case O(n)"""
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0
        self.length = 0
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this linked list"""
        # this actually helps me to see what's inside linkedList
        return 'LinkedList({})'.format(self.as_list())

    def setHead(self,head):
        self.head = head

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setNext(self,next):
        self.next = next

    def size(self):
        """ Gets the size of the Linked List
        AVERAGE: O(1) """
        return self.count

    def as_list(self):
        """Return a list of all items in this linked list"""
        items = []
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            items.append(current.value)
            current = current.next
        return items

    def append(self, item):
        new_node = ListNode(item)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        # Otherwise insert after tail node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
        # Update tail node
        self.tail = new_node
        # Update length
        self.size += 1

    def get_at_index(self, index):
        """Return the item at the given index in this linked list, or
        raise ValueError if the given index is out of range of the list size.
        Best case running time: O(1) if it's head or no value,
        Worst case running time: O(n) if it's in the tail [TODO]"""
        if not (0 <= index < self.size):
            raise ValueError('List index out of range: {}'.format(index))
        counter = self.head
        for i in range(index):
            counter = counter.next
        return counter.value


    def prepend(self, item):
        """Insert the given item at the head of this linked list"""
        """Best case Omega(1)"""
        """Worst case O(1)"""
        new_node = ListNode(item)
        # Insert before head node
        new_node.next = self.head
        # Update head node
        self.head = new_node
        # Check if list was empty
        if self.tail is None:
            self.tail = new_node
        # Update length
        self.size += 1

    def insert(self, value, index):
        """ Inserts value at a specific index
        BEST: O(1)
        WORST: O(i -1)
        """

        if not (0 <= index <= self.size):
            raise ValueError('List index out of range: {}'.format(index))
        node = ListNode(value)
        prev = self.get_at_index(index)

        if index == 0:
           self.append(value)
        elif index == self.size:
             self.append(value)
        else:
            new_node = ListNode(value)
            node = self.head
            previous = None
            for i in range(index):
                previous = node
                node = node.next
            previous.next = new_node
            new_node.next = node
            self.size += 1


    def remove(self, index):
        """Best case Omega(1)"""
        """Worst case O(n)"""
        previous = None
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            if current.value == self.get_at_index(index):
                if current is not self.head and current is not self.tail:
                    previous.next = current.next
                if current is self.head:
                    self.head = current.next
                if current is self.tail:
                    if previous is not None:
                        previous.next = None
                    self.tail = previous
                return
            previous = current
            current = current.next
        return -1



    def contains(self, value):
        """Return an item in this linked list if it's found"""
        """Best case Omega(1)"""
        """Worst case O(n)"""

        current = self.head  # Start at the head node
        while current is not None:
            if value == current.value:
                return True
            current = current.next  # Skip to the next node
        return False

def test_linked_list():
    ll = LinkedList()
    print(ll)
    print('Appending items:')
    ll.append('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('B')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('C')
    print(ll)
    print('head: {}'.format(ll.head))

    print('testing: Getting items by index:')
    #ll = LinkedList(['A', 'B', 'C'])
    print(ll)
    ll.insert('AA', 0)
    print(ll)

    ll.remove(1)
    print(ll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_linked_list()
```

It also passes all of these tests:

```
# ##############  TESTING  ###############
# ###########################################################


from io import StringIO
import sys


# custom assert function to handle tests
# input: count {List} - keeps track out how many tests pass and how many total
#        in the form of a two item array i.e., [0, 0]
# input: name {String} - describes the test
# input: test {Function} - performs a set of operations and returns a boolean
#        indicating if test passed
# output: {None}
def expect(count, name, test):
    if (count is None or not isinstance(count, list) or len(count) != 2):
        count = [0, 0]
    else:
        count[1] += 1

    result = 'false'
    error_msg = None
    try:
        if test():
            result = ' true'
            count[0] += 1
    except Exception as err:
        error_msg = str(err)

    print('  ' + (str(count[1]) + ')   ') + result + ' : ' + name)
    if error_msg is not None:
        print('       ' + error_msg + '\n')


class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        sys.stdout = self._stdout


# compare if two flat lists are equal
def lists_equal(lst1, lst2):
    if len(lst1) != len(lst2):
        return False
    for i in range(0, len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i] != lst2[i]:
            return False
    return True


print('ListNode Class')
test_count = [0, 0]


def test():
    node = ListNode()
    return isinstance(node, object)


expect(test_count, 'able to create an instance', test)


def test():
    node = ListNode()
    return hasattr(node, 'value')


expect(test_count, 'has value property', test)


def test():
    node = ListNode()
    return hasattr(node, 'next')


expect(test_count, 'has next property', test)


def test():
    node = ListNode()
    return node is not None and node.value is None


expect(test_count, 'has default value set to None', test)


def test():
    node = ListNode(5)
    return node is not None and node.value == 5


expect(test_count, 'able to assign a value upon instantiation', test)


def test():
    node = ListNode()
    node.value = 5
    return node is not None and node.value == 5


expect(test_count, 'able to reassign a value', test)


def test():
    node1 = ListNode(5)
    node2 = ListNode(10)
    node1.next = node2
    return (node1 is not None and node1.next is not None and
            node1.next.value == 10)


expect(test_count, 'able to point to another node', test)

print('PASSED: ' + str(test_count[0]) + ' / ' + str(test_count[1]) + '\n\n')


print('LinkedList Class')
test_count = [0, 0]


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return isinstance(linked_list, object)


expect(test_count, 'able to create an instance', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return hasattr(linked_list, 'head')


expect(test_count, 'has head property', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return hasattr(linked_list, 'tail')


expect(test_count, 'has tail property', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return hasattr(linked_list, 'length')


expect(test_count, 'has length property', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return linked_list is not None and linked_list.head is None


expect(test_count, 'default head set to None', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return linked_list is not None and linked_list.tail is None


expect(test_count, 'default tail set to None', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return linked_list is not None and linked_list.length == 0


expect(test_count, 'default length set to 0', test)

print('PASSED: ' + str(test_count[0]) + ' / ' + str(test_count[1]) + '\n\n')



print('LinkedList Contains Method')
test_count = [0, 0]


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    return (hasattr(linked_list, 'contains') and
            callable(getattr(linked_list, 'contains')))


expect(test_count, 'has contains method', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.append(5)
    linked_list.append(10)
    linked_list.append(15)
    return linked_list.contains(15) is True


expect(test_count, 'returns True if linked list contains value', test)


def test():
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.append(5)
    linked_list.append(10)
    linked_list.append(15)
    return linked_list.contains(8) is False


expect(test_count, 'returns False if linked list contains value', test)

print('PASSED: ' + str(test_count[0]) + ' / ' + str(test_count[1]) + '\n\n')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great job, looks really good! A few minor thoughts, on top of the existing answers:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    ...
```

You don't need to explicitly inherit from `object` if you're writing python3 code that doesn't require to be python2 compatible. This happens implicitly in python3. You've already done this for `Node`. Check out new style vs. old style classes if you want to learn more about this.

```
class LinkedList:
    ...
```

Moreover, you could define a function to add multiple values, such as:

```
def extend(self, vals):
    for val in vals:
        self.append(val)
```

You can also use that in your `__init__` if initial values are provided.

Additionally, you could define an `__iter__` function that implements a generator. This could help you with tasks for which you don't want to use `to_list()` and allocate the memory for a list.

```
def __iter__(self):
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        yield curr
        curr = curr.next
```

Lastly, I don't like using `next` as a variable, because it's already built-in, but that's not going to cause any trouble here.

Answer (score 2):

use """ """ instead of multiple """

from

```
    """Initialize this linked list and append the given items, if any"""
    """Best case Omega(1)"""
    """Worst case O(n)"""
```

to

```
    """
    Initialize this linked list and append the given items, if any
    Best case Omega(1)
    Worst case O(n)
    """
```

as usual the representation can be a bit better 
from

```
print('PASSED: ' + str(test_count[0]) + ' / ' + str(test_count[1]) + '\n\n')
```

to

```
print('PASSED: {} / {}'.format(test_count[0], test_count[1]), end='\n\n')
```

end in print allows you to specify how to end the printed charachters, separating it from your actual data. the .format eliminates the need for str() each time while keeping a focus on your output

+1 for main function usage

else, you can use maybe add a .extend instead of multiple appends or make the append method take multiple parameters

like from

```
linked_list.append(5)
linked_list.append(10)
linked_list.append(15)
```

to

```
linked_list.extend([5, 10, 15])
```

else, instead of writing your own test functions, use the in-built one, will save you some pains, and is available everywhere (no need to rederive your functions each time)